# Why does my website load my stylesheet intermittently?

Tags: css

Hey guys, I was wondering if this is just a server problem or if I'm  missing something.

I have three different style sheets (`buttons.css, reset.css, indexstyle.css`) and it seems that at every 3 refreshes, I finally see my webpage the way it's supposed to. What's going on ?!

Comment: ok, it might sound dumb but, do you correctly include them into HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it might sound dumb but, do you correctly include them into HTML? .

```
<link href="/new/templates/creo/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/new/templates/creo/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

if you have done so, make sure nothing is overriding the styles. The styles might be loaded but overrided by something, and you can't get the final result.

I guess server has nothing to do with style sheets (browsers do), maybe just loading speed.

Comment: it's weird but my server can only load one css file at at time.... across all my files, not just within one file...